# RISCV/Rocket chip Emulator output log

Tags: riscv

I am trying to evaluate rocket core performance of existing benchmark and also other applications.

after I run emulator with benchmark code MT-MATMUL and check out the mt-matmul.riscv.out, I noticed that there are quite a lot of stall. Can someone explain to me how could I identify the cause of stall? I thought this simple loop should be predicted and should not have some many stalls which is really slow down the processor.

See below log:

C0:       1956 [1] pc=[0000000628] W[r 0=0000000000001418][0] R[r 5=0000000000001418] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[0002b107] fld     ft2, 0(t0)

C0:       1957 [1] pc=[000000062c] W[r 0=0000000000007730][0] R[r16=0000000000007730] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[00083007] fld     ft0, 0(a6)

C0:       1958 [1] pc=[0000000630] W[r 0=0000000000003380][0] R[r 6=0000000000003380] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[00033087] fld     ft1, 0(t1)

**C0:       1959 [1] pc=[0000000634] W[r16=0000000000007738][1] R[r16=0000000000007730] R[r 8=0000000000000013] inst=[00880813] addi    a6, a6, 8

C0:       1960 [0] pc=[0000000634] W[r 0=0000000000007738][0] R[r16=0000000000007730] R[r 8=0000000000000013] inst=[00880813] addi    a6, a6, 8

C0:       1961 [0] pc=[0000000634] W[r 0=0000000000007738][0] R[r16=0000000000007730] R[r 8=0000000000000013] inst=[00880813] addi    a6, a6, 8**

C0:       1962 [1] pc=[0000000638] W[r17=0000000000000014][1] R[r17=0000000000000013] R[r 1=0000000000000013] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1963 [1] pc=[000000063c] W[r 0=0000000000000001][0] R[r 1=0000000000000013] R[r 2=0000000000000013] inst=[0220f043] fmadd.d ft0, ft1, ft2, ft0

C0:       1964 [1] pc=[0000000640] W[r 5=0000000000001420][1] R[r 5=0000000000001418] R[r 8=0000000000000013] inst=[00828293] addi    t0, t0, 8

C0:       1965 [0] pc=[0000000640] W[r 0=0000000000001420][0] R[r 5=0000000000001418] R[r 8=0000000000000013] inst=[00828293] addi    t0, t0, 8

C0:       1966 [0] pc=[0000000640] W[r 0=0000000000001420][0] R[r 5=0000000000001418] R[r 8=0000000000000013] inst=[00828293] addi    t0, t0, 8

C0:       1967 [1] pc=[0000000644] W[r 0=0000000000007730][0] R[r16=0000000000007738] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[fe083c27] fsd     ft0, -8(a6)

C0:       1968 [1] pc=[0000000648] W[r 0=0000000000000001][0] R[r12=0000000000000020] R[r17=0000000000000014] inst=[ff1610e3] bne     a2, a7, pc - 32

C0:       1969 [1] pc=[0000000628] W[r 0=0000000000001420][0] R[r 5=0000000000001420] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[0002b107] fld     ft2, 0(t0)

C0:       1970 [1] pc=[000000062c] W[r 0=0000000000007738][0] R[r16=0000000000007738] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[00083007] fld     ft0, 0(a6)

C0:       1971 [1] pc=[0000000630] W[r 0=0000000000003380][0] R[r 6=0000000000003380] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[00033087] fld     ft1, 0(t1)

C0:       1972 [1] pc=[0000000634] W[r16=0000000000007740][1] R[r16=0000000000007738] R[r 8=0000000000000017] inst=[00880813] addi    a6, a6, 8

C0:       1973 [0] pc=[0000000634] W[r 0=0000000000007740][0] R[r16=0000000000007738] R[r 8=0000000000000017] inst=[00880813] addi    a6, a6, 8

C0:       1974 [0] pc=[0000000634] W[r 0=0000000000007740][0] R[r16=0000000000007738] R[r 8=0000000000000017] inst=[00880813] addi    a6, a6, 8

C0:       1975 [1] pc=[0000000638] W[r17=0000000000000015][1] R[r17=0000000000000014] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

**C0:       1982 [1] pc=[0000000628] W[r 0=0000000000001428][0] R[r 5=0000000000001428] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[0002b107] fld     ft2, 0(t0)

C0:       1983 [1] pc=[000000062c] W[r 0=0000000000007740][0] R[r16=0000000000007740] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[00083007] fld     ft0, 0(a6)

C0:       1984 [1] pc=[0000000630] W[r 0=0000000000003380][0] R[r 6=0000000000003380] R[r 0=0000000000000000] inst=[00033087] fld     ft1, 0(t1)

C0:       1985 [1] pc=[0000000634] W[r16=0000000000007748][1] R[r16=0000000000007740] R[r 8=0000000000000017] inst=[00880813] addi    a6, a6, 8

C0:       1986 [0] pc=[0000000634] W[r 0=0000000000007748][0] R[r16=0000000000007740] R[r 8=0000000000000017] inst=[00880813] addi    a6, a6, 8

C0:       1987 [0] pc=[0000000634] W[r 0=0000000000007748][0] R[r16=0000000000007740] R[r 8=0000000000000017] inst=[00880813] addi    a6, a6, 8

C0:       1988 [1] pc=[0000000638] W[r17=0000000000000016][1] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1989 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1990 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1991 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1992 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1993 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1994 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1995 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1996 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1997 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1998 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       1999 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2000 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2001 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2002 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2003 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2004 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2005 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2006 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2007 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2008 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2009 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2010 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2011 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2012 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2013 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2014 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2015 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2016 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2017 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2018 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2019 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2020 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1

C0:       2021 [0] pc=[0000000638] W[r 0=0000000000000016][0] R[r17=0000000000000015] R[r 1=0000000000000017] inst=[0018889b] addiw   a7, a7, 1**

The assembly code is simple

```
 5e8:  02b645bb            divw      a1,a2,a1
 5ec:   02a5853b             mulw     a0,a1,a0
 5f0:   00a585bb             addw     a1,a1,a0
 5f4:   06b55e63             ble          a1,a0,670 <matmul+0x88>
 5f8:   02a6083b             mulw     a6,a2,a0
 5fc:    00361e93             slli           t4,a2,0x3
 600:   00381813             slli           a6,a6,0x3
 604:   010787b3             add        a5,a5,a6
 608:   010686b3             add        a3,a3,a6
 60c:   04c05863              blez        a2,65c <matmul+0x74>
 610:   00070e13             mv          t3,a4
 614:   00068313             mv          t1,a3
 618:   00000393             li              t2,0
 61c:   000e0293             mv          t0,t3
 620:   00078813             mv          a6,a5
 624:   00000893             li              a7,0
 628:   0002b107             fld           ft2,0(t0)
 62c:   00083007             fld           ft0,0(a6)
 630:   00033087             fld           ft1,0(t1) # 3000 <input2_data+0x1c80>
 634:   00880813             addi       a6,a6,8
 638:   0018889b             addiw    a7,a7,1
 63c:   0220f043              fmadd.d               ft0,ft1,ft2,ft0
 640:   00828293             addi       t0,t0,8
 644:   fe083c27              fsd          ft0,-8(a6)
 648:   ff1610e3              bne        a2,a7,628 <matmul+0x40>
 64c:   0013839b             addiw    t2,t2,1
 650:   01de0e33            add        t3,t3,t4
 654:   00830313             addi       t1,t1,8
 658:   fc7612e3              bne        a2,t2,61c <matmul+0x34>
 65c:   0015051b             addiw    a0,a0,1
 660:   01d787b3             add        a5,a5,t4
 664:   01d686b3             add        a3,a3,t4
 668:   fab512e3             bne        a0,a1,60c <matmul+0x24>
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the cause of the stalls, especially from the output log is not easy. This is also true for most processors in general. Processors can stall for a number of reasons, and it is most often due to cache or TLB misses.

You will need to modify rocket to either add in debug statements for emulation or even add more performance counters to track these stall events. Either way, it will be a substantial amount of work.

Comment: What I am trying to evaluate is mainly the core performance itself, so Is there any easy way to reduce the impact of TLB or Cache miss? Like increase the TLB or cache size and only simulate in emulator only, or even lock or load the text/data segment directly in L1I/D $ instead of in DRAM?

Comment: Is there any other way to visually display pipeline?
Or at least identify the cause of stall is due to I$ miss? D$ miss? Register data dependency at assembly level?

Comment: You can increase the TLB or cache size, but then you are simulating a different core. Rocket-chip is a complete SoC, intended to be manufactured in silicon. For exploration of architectures that may not be synthesizable, you could use a software simulator like sniper (http://snipersim.org) whose CPI stacks feature might be what you want.

Comment: you misunderstood my question. I am trying to use part of rocket core without cache(if my application can be fit in SRAM), therefore all I care is about the core itself so I have to run some signal processing benchmark to see if the core is fast enough to handle huge amount of computation without breaking real-time from app point of view.

Comment: As I am not able to run stuff standalone I am using Rocket-chip SoC emulator to evaluate the core and try yo eliminate the side effect from cache(that is why I re-sized TLB or cache without considering synthesizable of routeable, on in emulator , as i might remove the cache eventually and associated hardware module, it is possible but need some efforts)

Comment: Perhaps the simplest solution might be to make the caches bigger and to put your code into a loop and repeat it many times. That way the data will likely be in the cache so you can see what the performance would be like with cache hits.